# How do I randomly select k points from N points in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I use this code to create and plot `N` points:

```
N=input('No. of Nodes:');
data = rand(N,2) % Randomly generated n no. of nodes
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
plot(x,y,'*');
```

How do I choose `k` points (with probability `p=0.25`) out of `N` points, then color those `k` points red and leave the other points as `*`.

Comment: Your last statement conflicts with itself. Do you want to randomly pick `k` values from `N` values, or do you want to pick values randomly from a length `N` vector with a probability `p`? These two approaches can have different results.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take. The first solution is to randomly pick `k` values from `N` values, which will ensure that you *always* have `k` points chosen. The second solution is to pick values randomly with each having an average probability `p` of being chosen, which could result in as little as `0` or as many as `N` being randomly chosen.

- **Picking `k` from `N` values:**

  You can use the function [RANDPERM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html) to create a random permutation of the integers `1` through `N`, then pick the first `k` values in the permuted list and replot them as red:

  ```
  index = randperm(N);
  plot(x(index(1:k)),y(index(1:k)),'r*');
  ```
- **Picking values with an average probability `p`:**

  You can use the [RAND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html) function to pick a random value from `0` to `1` for each of your `N` values, then choose the ones with a random value less than or equal to your average probability `p` and replot them as red:

  ```
  index = (rand(N,1) <= p);
  plot(x(index),y(index),'r*');
  ```

Comment: or use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/randsample.html) for the first case.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood, for each of the `N` random point you want to flip a coin to decide whether to select it or not (where the coin has a `p=0.25` probability of success!)

```
data = rand(N,2);             %# generate random points
index = (rand(N,1) <= p);     %# roll coins to pick with prob p
data(~index, :) = [];         %# keep only selected points
```

This ends up being equivalent to only generating `p*N` random points in the first place (at least you approach this number as `N` grows larger)...

```
data = rand(p*N, 2);          %# directly generate p*N number of points
```

you can test that last statement for various values of N:

```
fprintf('1st = %d \n', p*N)
fprintf('2nd = %d \n', sum(rand(N,1) <= p))
```

Comment: thankx a lot , i also need those k chosen points, as u told data(~index,:)=[]; thankx for help

Comment: if we have to find distance between any point of data=rand(N,2) (say first) from any point of data(~index, :) = [];(say first of this also), how can we use data(~index, :) = []; matrix in following statement?

dist=sqrt((data(1,1)-data(~index,1))^2+(data(1,2)-data(~index,2))^2).

my question is as we are taking first element of data as data(1,1) and data (1,2). how do we take take first element of data(~index,:) matrix?

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand the question, but know that `data(~index,:)=[]` simply removes all the elements not selected. So if you plan to use both selected and non-selected points, you SHOULDNT remove them, instead you can perhaps store them in two different matrices: `selected = data(index,:);` and `not_selected = data(~index,:);` . Then if you want compute the distance between two points `i` and `j` each from one set, use: `dist_ij = sqrt(sum((selected(i,:)-not_selected(j,:)).^2));`

Comment: thankx again my friend, as u didn't response from here first, so posted it as another question. can i remove that question from board or let be there? thankx anyways

Comment: @amro selected = data(index,:); is giving me following error

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.