# i need to pick a random xy point from a list of xy points

Tags: matlab

in mat lab if i read a data set into a new structure with an x and y value and now from that list i need to choose two radom points from that data list of data there are like 400 points and i just need to choose two points so i can draw a line between the two points trying to do a least means of squares problem   please help me

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I randomly select k points from N points in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856141/how-do-i-randomly-select-k-points-from-n-points-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [RANDPERM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html) to get a shuffled list of indices, then simply take the first two indices:

```
data = rand(400,2);

ind = randperm(400);
p1 = data(ind(1),:);
p2 = data(ind(2),:);
```