# Random order of rows Matlab

Tags: matlab, shuffle

Say we have a matrix of size  100x3

How would you shuffle the rows in MATLAB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I randomly select k points from N points in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856141/how-do-i-randomly-select-k-points-from-n-points-in-matlab)

Comment: It is not about selecting, it is about "desorder" or shuffle the rows of a matrix

Comment: Actually, you're right. It's not quite the same question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To shuffle the rows of a matrix, you can use [RANDPERM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html)

```
shuffledArray = orderedArray(randperm(size(orderedArray,1)),:);
```

`randperm` will generate a list of `N` random values and sort them, returning the second output of `sort` as result.

Comment: Your solution runs about 2.5x faster than mine does, at least on my computer.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Works like a charm. If you instead want to shuffle the columns of a matrix the solution is: shuffledArray = orderedArray(:,randperm(size(orderedArray,2)))

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by creating a new random index for the matrix rows via Matlab's **randsample** function.

```
matrix=matrix(randsample(1:length(matrix),length(matrix)),:);
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `'false'` - if sampling with replacement, the resulting matrix will contain duplicate rows, while others will have disappeared. In the case sampling without replacement, `randsample` calls `randperm`, which should thus only be marginally slower than calling `randperm` directly.

Answer (score 3):

While reading the [answer of Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5444297/3798217) I found it little bit tough to read, tough to understand. In Mathworks I found a similar [question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/324891-how-to-randomly-shuffle-the-row-elements-of-a-predefined-matrix) where the answer is more readable, easier to understand. Taking idea from Mathworks I have written a function:

```
function ret = shuffleRow(mat)

[r c] = size(mat);
shuffledRow = randperm(r);
ret = mat(shuffledRow, :);
```

Actually it does the same thing as [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5444297/3798217). But I think it is little bit more readable, easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

For large datasets, you can use the custom [Shuffle](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27076-shuffle?s_tid=srchtitle) function

> It uses D.E. Knuth's shuffle algorithm (also called Fisher-Yates) and the cute KISS random number generator (G. Marsaglia).