# How to select random samples from a dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I randomly select k points from N points in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856141/how-do-i-randomly-select-k-points-from-n-points-in-matlab)

Let's say I have a dataset that includes 10,000 rows of data. What is the best way to create a subset that includes 1,000 randomly chosen rows?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use randperm for this task:

Sampling without replacement:

```
nRows = 10000; % number of rows
nSample = 1000; % number of samples

rndIDX = randperm(nRows); 

newSample = data(rndIDX(1:nSample), :);
```

Sampling with replacement:

```
nRows = 10000; % number of rows
nSample = 1000; % number of samples

rndIDX = randi(nRows, nSample, 1); 

newSample = data(rndIDX, :);
```

Comment: Can you show an example for sampling without replacement? Thanks!

Comment: @robguinness: Actually, this example is sampling without replacement.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, now that I read the documentation for randperm. So for sampling with replacement I would use need to use randi instead?

Comment: @robguinness: yes, it's `randi` for sampling with replacement. Shall I add a code example to my answer?

Comment: I see you've already done so, thanks! BTW, I ended up using randsample from the statistics toolbox in my code, but I think your answer is useful for those who don't have that toolbox. Besides, they basically do the same thing with the same number of lines of code.

Answer (score 6):

Use `randperm` in combination with the number of rows. If `x` is your matrix:

```
nrows = size(x,1);
nrand = 1000; % Choose 1000 rows
assert(nrand<=nrows, 'You cannot choose more rows than exist in the matrix');
rand_rows = randperm(nrows, nrand);
xx = x(rand_rows,:);  % Select the random rows from x
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the statistics toolbox R2012+, you can use [datasample](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/datasample.html).

```
subset = datasample(data,1000)
```

`subset` will be a randomly selected subset of data consisting of 1000 samples.

To sample without replacement, use:

```
subset = datasample(data,1000,'Replace',false)
```

If you have an older version of the toolbox, you can use [randsample](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
rndIdx = randsample(size(data,1),1000,true); % with replacement
subset = samples(rndIdx(1:1000), :);

rndIdx = randsample(size(data,1),1000,false); % without replacement
subset = samples(rndIdx(1:1000), :);
```

But using randsample is more or less the same as H.Muster's answer (which I have accepted as the best because it doesn't require any toolbox).

Note: For more info on the
    difference between sampling with replacement vs. sampling without
    replacement, see [this page](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you written any code so far. The following [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) link shows examples of random sampling. Take a look at it for ideas.

Also a code here with randsample from statistics toolbox. Just a logic and you may have to adjust it accordingly.

matrix m of N rows 
pull a random sample of n rows from m

`Sample = m(randsample(1:N,n),:)`

`randsample(1:N,n)`

Above results in a sequence of n random integers from 1 to N.